# How to change a timezone to another timezone in netsuite while using restlet

Tags: javascript, date, time, timezone, netsuite

I am sending lastmodified date via url in restlet but the problem is I have to modify the date based on user's timezone where restlet is deployed. SO, I need to change the timezone to his timezone before putting date in last modified filter. The problem I am facing is when I am using the new Date() function it is always changing the timezone to PST time zone instead of users time zone. Have a look at the question.

```
function getCompanyCurrentDateTime(UTCtime) { 
    var UTCtime = UTCtime; // Utc time is in milliseconds 
    var companyTimeZone = nlapiLoadConfiguration('companyinformation').getFieldText('timezone');
    nlapiLogExecution("DEBUG", "companyTimeZone",companyTimeZone );
    var timeZoneOffSet = (companyTimeZone.indexOf('(GMT)') == 0) ? 0 : new Number(companyTimeZone.substr(4, 6).replace(/\+|:00/gi, '').replace(/:30/gi, '.5'));
    nlapiLogExecution("DEBUG", "timeZoneOffSet",timeZoneOffSet ); // timezone offset is in hours and minutes 
    var timeZoneOffSetStr = timeZoneOffSet.toString();
    var timeZoneOffSetRes = timeZoneOffSetStr.split(".");
    var timeZoneOffSetMilli = Number(timeZoneOffSetRes[0])*3600*1000 + Number(timeZoneOffSetRes[1])*60*1000;
    nlapiLogExecution("DEBUG", "timeZoneOffSetMilli",timeZoneOffSetMilli );
    var NewcompanyDateTime = new Date(UTCtime + (timeZoneOffSetMilli));
    nlapiLogExecution("DEBUG", "NewcompanyDateTime",NewcompanyDateTime );
    return NewcompanyDateTime;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) as library for timezone corrections than doing manual offset calculations.

You will need to include momentjs and its timezone data in your script as library

```
//I believe you already know code using nlapiLoadConfiguration on getting timezone and date format
moment(new Date()).tz(getComapnyTimeZone()).format(getCompanyDateFormat());
moment(new Date()).tz(getComapnyTimeZone()).format(getCompanyDateTimeFormat());
```

Comment: It seems pretty good idea but I do not have olson value of the time zone. I have the descrition e.g (GMT+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi , I do not have 'Asia/Calcutta'  this format. Do I need to convert or is there any way momentjs can convert it for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the argument `UTCtime` is already universal standard, and you want to convert it to the browser's local time, you may want to try something like

```
function localTime(UTCtime)  // convert UTC in ms to local time in ms
{ return UTCtime + (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
}
```

As noted in the question, `getCompanyCurrentDateTime(UTCtime)` will convert `UTCtime` to PST just as long as company time uses PST and that is the offset you apply to the parameter value!

Comment: Actually there is no browser here. I mean there is no client, I have to change the timezone according to server timezone.

Comment: According to part 3 of this [scripting tip](http://codeboxllc.com/ksc/2014/05/23/scripting-tip-63-netsuite-date-and-timezone-api-guide/) `new Date()` on the server always returns PST or PSD and hints at automatic conversions for times seen by users. Sorry I can't add anything further.